# How to pass lamda as a function pointer argument of member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I learned how to pass member functions to another member function as a function pointer argument.

Now, I'm trying to pass lamda as a function pointer argument of member function.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    int sub(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
    typedef int (Test::*funcPtr)(int a, int b);
    int myFunc(funcPtr func, int a, int b)
    {
        return (this->*func)(a, b);
    }
    void setup()
    {
        cout << myFunc(&Test::add, 5, 3) << endl;
        cout << myFunc(&Test::sub, 5, 3) << endl;
        cout << myFunc([](int a, int b) {return a * b;}, 5, 3) << endl; //ERROR!!!
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.setup();
}
```

Result:

> Error: : No viable conversion from lambda to 'Test::funcPtr' (aka 'int
>   (Test::*)(int, int)')

Expected Result:

```
8
2
15
```

How should I correct my code so I can get the expected result?

Comment: Your function takes a pointer to a member function. `add` and `sub` are member functions, the lambda is not.

Comment: You can't. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: So is it not possible to pass the multiply function to `myFunc` without having an actual `mult()` function?

Comment: Why does `myFunc` take a *member* function pointer to begin with? You could use a regular function pointer, and make `add` and `sub` static.

Comment: @ZackLee I have an edit in my answer you may want to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one option is making your functions `static` and then use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as type:

```
using funcType = std::function<int(int, int)>;
int myFunc(funcType func, int a, int b)
{
    return func(a, b);
}

void setup()
{
    cout << myFunc(Test::add, 5, 3) << endl;
    cout << myFunc(Test::sub, 5, 3) << endl;
    cout << myFunc([](int a, int b) {return a * b;}, 5, 3) << endl;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/iX9I3j)

Thanks to [@holyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) the other option is using regular function pointer(member functions need to be `static`):

```
typedef int (*funcPtr)(int a, int b);
//or:
//using funcPtr =  int (*)(int a, int b);
int myFunc(funcPtr func, int a, int b)
{
    return (*func)(a, b);
}
```

and also template:

```
template<typename funcType>
int myFunc(funcType func, int a, int b)
{
    return func(a, b);
}
void setup()
{
    cout << myFunc(Test::add, 5, 3) << endl;
    cout << myFunc(Test::sub, 5, 3) << endl;
    cout << myFunc([](int a, int b) {return a * b;}, 5, 3) << endl;
}
```

[regular function pointer live](https://godbolt.org/z/T-SlpG), [template live](https://godbolt.org/z/BNkDnE)

---

**EDIT**

The examples provided above are working only with static member function. To invoke non-static member functions you can use [pointer to member function type](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

```
using funcPtr = int(Test::*)(int a, int b);
int myFunc(funcPtr func, int a, int b)
{
    return invoke(func, this, a, b);
}

//..
// call:
cout << myFunc(&Test::add, 5, 3) << endl;
```

pointer to non-static member function [live](https://godbolt.org/z/KPZnHZ)

Comment: In this case you could use a regular function pointer as well.

Comment: This won't compile.

Comment: @0x499602D2 the member functions has to be static, check the live link please